# How to export a result from function? (updated with more code)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Stackoverflow, hello. I didn't found any information about exporting a data (list in my case) from a "function"

The end of my code is:

```
def namesearch():
    with open ('recipes.txt') as f:
        dishnames = []
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            # print (line)
            line2=line.split()
            if len(line2) <= 3:
                pass
                try:
                    a=(int(line2[0])/1)
                except IndexError:
                    pass
                except ValueError:
                    dishnames.append(line2)
        for i in dishnames:
            if len(i) > 1:
                j=' '.join(i)
            else:
                j = str(i[0])
            dishnames_string.append(j)

namesearch()

def search_ingridientsnames():
    with open('recipes.txt') as f:
        ingridient_names = []
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            # print (line)
            line2 = line.split()
            try:
                i=0
                if len(line2) > 3 or len(line2)<1:
                    ingridient_names.append(line2[0])
            except IndexError:
                ingridient_names.append('_')
        # print(ingridient_names)
    ingridient_names_final=[i.split(',') for i in ','.join(ingridient_names).split(',_,')]
print(ingridient_names_final)
search_ingridientsnames()

print (dishnames_string)
print (ingridient_names_final)
```

The result is

```
>> [['Egg', 'Milk', 'Tomato'], ['Duck', 'Water', 'Honey', 'Soy'], ['Potato', 'Garlic', 'Gouda'], ['Beef', 'Sweet', 'Pita', 'Wine', 'Tomato']]
>> ['Omelette', 'Peking Duck', 'Baked potato', 'Fajitos']
[]
```

Do you see that? 
The first `print(ingridient_names_final)` in the end of function - writing the list from function and it's ok.
As you see, I have another value from function, `print (dishnames_string)`, which is also a part of function - the result of the work is the list. 
However, when I print again the value from function `print (search_ingridientsnames)` - the result is [].
And I even can't write print(list(search_ingridientsnames)) - the result is an error.
How could I recieve the same result from function launching?

The result should be:

```
>> [['Egg', 'Milk', 'Tomato'], ['Duck', 'Water', 'Honey', 'Soy'], ['Potato', 'Garlic', 'Gouda'], ['Beef', 'Sweet', 'Pita', 'Wine', 'Tomato']]
>> ['Omelette', 'Peking Duck', 'Baked potato', 'Fajitos']
>> [['Egg', 'Milk', 'Tomato'], ['Duck', 'Water', 'Honey', 'Soy'], ['Potato', 'Garlic', 'Gouda'], ['Beef', 'Sweet', 'Pita', 'Wine', 'Tomato']]
```

**UPD**

[image: However, if I try to enter print (search_ingridientsnames()) as everybody helps, the result is the required list and "NONE" after that. WTF?]

Comment: You need to __call__ the function. `print (search_ingridientsnames())`

Comment: You are printing the function as an **object**. If you want to print its return value, you need to call it: `print (search_ingridientsnames())`

Comment: I don't see how you are getting that output.  Two of the three print statements are printing _function objects_ instead of printing the _results_ of calling the function.  You should be getting two of the `<function>` output messages.

Answer (score 0):

The code is printing exactly what you asked for.  To print the result of the function you need to use:

```
print (search_ingridientsnames())
```

Answer (score 0):

From a first hand look i can say that python is interpreting the result of the print statement as an object and is therefore printing what you see on the console. You need to write it as print(search_ingredientsname()).

Comment: updated a code. now trying to recieve just a value from function (list), but get an empty []

Comment: or if I try to do as everybody advices - print (search_ingridientsnames()) - i have the result, and then "None"

Comment: Could you tell me the contents of recipe.txt?
i think there's a logical error somewhere that's causing you to populate an empty list after executing the function.